# To map Model classes to ViewModel classes or aggregate Model classes in ViewModel classes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm curious as to what people consider better practice, between duplicating model structure in the view model and using a mapping tool to move data between the two, or aggregate the model inside the view model, i.e. have a property on the view model class that is a reference to the actual model.  Which is considered a better approach in general?

Comment: Isn't this the same as your last question?

Comment: @jfar, no, my last question is about where to use data annotation attributes.  That I mentioned the two approaches I actually ask about in this question doesn't change what the other question actually asks.  I separated them to try and avoid asking too much in one question.

Comment: Then you may want to consider removing this line from your other question: "Should I stick with my current approach and ViewModelBase design, or make an early switch to the mapping approach?"

Comment: @jfar, thanks, I didn't realise I had actually asked that there - obviously I was thinking of both questions at once - but I've changed that question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "better" approach will always be having a distinct view model for each view, and then using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) or something similar to handle the guts of the mappings for you

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public MyViewModel() { }
  public MyViewModel( MyModel model )
  {
    AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(model, this);
  }
}
```

It will vary in practice sometimes, but having a distinct, concise viewmodel will offer the most flexibility.

Comment: I think your subjective answer could better be phrased, "better for me" approach, but I see where you're coming from.  However, I think this would require a T4 template for the view model classes, to mitigate the widespread duplication of code.

Comment: I'm going to respectfully disagree with the "better for me" statement. There are many similar questions on here giving this same answer as a "best practice" and many well respected programmers in the .NET MVC follow the same rules (http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2008/10/23/our-opinions-on-the-asp-net-mvc-introducing-the-thunderdome-principle.aspx and http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/06/29/how-we-do-mvc-view-models.aspx as examples). You asked for the better approach in general, I answered with what myself and many others have found it to be = )

Comment: I don't see any connection at all in the Miller blog with what you are asserting.  the Bogard blog offers a neat way to achieve what you advocate, but is not enough to convince me that that way is indeed better.  Thanks for the input though, discourse is healthy.